# Why isn't overflow: scroll working properly inside a bootstrap-vue modal?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-vue

so I have the following bootstrap modal:

```
</template>
    <div>
        <b-modal v-model="show_modal">
            <p>blah blah blah blah blah</p>
            <div id="entity-list">
                 <div>item 1</div>
                 <div>item 2</div>
                 <div>item 3</div>
                 <div>item 4</div>
                 <div>item 5</div>
                 <div>item 6</div>
                 <div>item 7</div>
             </div>
        </b-modal>
        <b-button type="button" variant="primary" @click="show_modal= !show_modal">Toggle Modal</b-button>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data: function() {
        return  {
            show_modal: false
        }
    }
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
#entity-list {
    max-height: 250px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    div {
        height: 40px;
    }
}
</style>
```

So for some reason I can't scroll with my mouse's scroll wheel, but if I try hard enough, I can find the scroll bar and use that to scroll through the list. But the mouse scroll wheel is buggy and just scrolls the main window instead of the entity-list div.

I tried this code in Safari and I was able to scroll through the entity list. This seems to be a chrome specific bug. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Not able to reproduce this https://codepen.io/srajagop/pen/QRmRXw. You might have someother css that is doing something

Comment: Have you changed your zoom level? Press `Ctrl` +`0` to make sure it's reset. Can you reproduce this in a fiddle/snippet tool? Also, make sure the SCSS is compiled correctly (check the CSS output in page source).

Comment: it's weird, but disconnecting my laptop from my monitors fixed the issue. i am able to scroll inside the entity-list on my main laptop screen.